# Показ рекламы через несколько открытий активити

Tags: android

Есть такой метод, который проверяет, если есть доступ к интернету, то показываем рекламу, а  потом запускает активити, если нет доступа просто открывает активити. Хотелось бы сделать так, чтобы реклама показывалась через 5 открытий активити. Как этого добиться?

```
private void showAds(Intent i, Context c) {
    final Intent intent = i;
    if (NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatus(c) == NetworkUtil.TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED) {
        startActivity(intent);
    } else if (NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatus(c) == NetworkUtil.TYPE_MOBILE | NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatus(c) == NetworkUtil.TYPE_WIFI) {
        adMob.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        if (adMob.isLoaded()) {
            adMob.show();
        } else {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        adMob.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                startActivity(intent);
                adMob.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: можно упростить, сразу проверяйте adMob.isLoaded(), без проверки инета. Переменную ставите =-1 в onCreate увеличивайте, потом проверка на деление без остатка на 5 и показ

Answer (score 0):

Я у себя сделал таким образом - создал счетчик и сохранял число, при ткытии сравнивал, например если равно к примеру 4, то показывал и счетчик обнулял. И так по кругу.
Засверлил примерно так:

Во первых, что бы не плодить кроликов, все причиндалы вынес в отдельный класс:

```
private SharedPreferences count_bus_interstitial;
public static final String
        BUS_NUMBER = "bus_number",
        START_STATION = "start_station",
        END_STATION = "end_station",
        SAVED_TEXT = "interstitial_adw";

public class NetworkChecker {

public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm =
            (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = null;
    if (cm != null) {
        activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    }
    return activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
}
```

}

И далее там где нужно долбим таким образом:

```
 count_bus_interstitial = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    int interstitialInt = count_bus_interstitial.getInt(SAVED_TEXT, 0);
    checkInterstitial(interstitialInt);

    if (NetworkChecker.isNetworkAvailable(getActivity() && interstitialInt == MyConst.MAX_TIME_ADW) {
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

    }
```

Ну а тут просто записываю значение и увеличиваю его на 1. А если достигла максимума - сбрасываю.

```
 private void checkInterstitial(int savedText) {
    if (savedText >= MyConst.MAX_TIME_ADW) {
        savedText = MyConst.MIN_TIME_ADW;
    }
    count_bus_interstitial = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = count_bus_interstitial.edit();
    editor.putInt(SAVED_TEXT, ++savedText);
    editor.apply();
}
```

Comment: А можно ссылку на такую реализацию? Я с SharedPreferences не сталкивалась, заодно посмотрю это тоже. Не очень поняла что за переменная savedText и count_bus_interstitial

Comment: я дополнил ответ, в принципе там код написан полностью